# could not find com.affolestad.material-dialogs

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I imported Android Studio project but was stuck at this error.
I even updated my SDK and gradle build 
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.5.2.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.5.2/material-dialogs-0.7.5.2.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.5.2/material-dialogs-0.7.5.2.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/akki/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.5.2/material-dialogs-0.7.5.2.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/akki/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.5.2/material-dialogs-0.7.5.2.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/akki/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.5.2/material-dialogs-0.7.5.2.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/akki/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.5.2/material-dialogs-0.7.5.2.jar
>        Required by:
>            WallpaperTemplate-master:app:unspecified

Answer (score 1):

This library is not on jcenter or maven.

You have to add the [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/docs/) repo as described in the readme.

```
repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

Comment: I am really new to development can you please guide me how to add jitpack.io repo ?

Comment: @AkshayKatariya You can add it in the build.gradle in your module, or you can add the repo in the existing repository block in your build.gradle in the root folder.