# Could not find com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.6.2

Tags: android, gradle

I am using [material dialogs lib](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) in my android application. I imported a module and this is lib gradle. I have already checked this thread [could not find com.affolestad.material-dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118030/could-not-find-com-affolestad-material-dialogs) but I have already thats suggested there. I don't know when I sync it then it looks for some other version of this lib. In build.gradle it is `0.9.4.7` but it looks for `0.8.6.2`

module build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compille 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compille fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compille 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.7'
}
```

app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-dialogs')
}
```

Error

```
  Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  > Could not find com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.6.2.
    Searched in the following locations:
        file:/C:/Users/williams/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.pom
        file:/C:/Users/williams/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.jar
        file:/C:/Users/williams/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.pom
        file:/C:/Users/williams/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.jar
        file:/C:/Users/williams/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.pom
        file:/C:/Users/williams/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.jar
        file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio Preview/gradle/m2repository/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.pom
        file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio Preview/gradle/m2repository/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.jar
        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.pom
        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.jar
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.pom
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.jar
        file:/D:/React Native/application/node_modules/react-native/android/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.pom
        file:/D:/React Native/application/node_modules/react-native/android/com/github/afollestad/material-dialogs/commons/0.8.6.2/commons-0.8.6.2.jar
    Required by:
        project :app > project :react-native-dialogs
```

I deleted *.iml* files, invalidated cache also that didn't work for me.

Comment: There is something strange. The library that it is looking for is com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons not com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Yep I couldn't manage to get it worked, weird. I went to some other alternatives

Comment: check the answer below. There is also a issue with the same answer: https://github.com/aakashns/react-native-dialogs/issues/62

Answer (score 1):

This issue doens't depend by

```
 compille 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.7'
```

Instead it depends by this line:

```
implementation project(':react-native-dialogs')
```

Checking in the [github project](https://github.com/aakashns/react-native-dialogs/blob/master/android/build.gradle#L34) you can find this dependency. It is an old module that is only on jitpack.

You have to include in your `app/build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have 3 choices:

1. Delete '.gradle' folder from your project root folder and then try again.
2. Force Android Studio to redownload dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765077/6507689
3. Make sure you have unchecked working offline: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22870183/6507689